# How to read ascii formatted table in python

Tags: python, csv

I have some configuration data in the below format. What is the best way to parse this data in python? I checked the `csv` module and briefly [this](http://docs.astropy.org/en/latest/io/ascii/index.html) module. Couldn't figureout how to use it. Existing parser is hacked in perl.

```
|------------+-----------------+--------|
| ColHead1   | Col_______Head2 | CH3    |
|------------+-----------------+--------|
| abcdefg000 | *               | somev1 |
| abcdefg001 | *               | somev2 |
| abcdefg002 | *               |        |
| abcdefg003 | *               |        |
| abcdefg004 | *               |        |
| abcdefg005 | *               |        |
| abcdefg006 | *               |        |
| abcdefg007 | *               |        |
| abcdefg008 | *               |        |
| abcdefg009 | *               |        |
| abcdefg010 | *               |        |
|------------+-----------------+--------|
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Parsing a pretty printed table into Python objects](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18970491/parsing-a-pretty-printed-table-into-python-objects)

Answer (score 2):

You can try something like that:

```
def parse(ascii_table):
    header = []
    data = []
    for line in filter(None, ascii_table.split('\n')):
        if '-+-' in line:
            continue
        if not header:
            header = filter(lambda x: x!='|', line.split())
            continue
        data.append(['']*len(header))
        splitted_line = filter(lambda x: x!='|', line.split())
        for i in range(len(splitted_line)):
            data[-1][i]=splitted_line[i]
    return header, data
```

Answer (score 1):

here is another (similar) way to do it
if it is in a file:

```
with open(filepath) as f:
    for line in f:
        if '-+-' in line or 'Head' in line:
            continue
        # strip '|' off the ends then split on '|'
        c1, c2, c3 =  line.strip('|').split('|')
        print 'Col1: {}\tCol2: {}\tCol3: {}'.format(c1,c2,c3)
```

or a string variable:

```
for line in ascii_table.split('\n'):
    if '-+-' in line or 'Head' in line:
        continue
    c1, c2, c3 =  line.strip('|').split('|')
    print 'Col1: {}\tCol2: {}\tCol3: {}'.format(c1,c2,c3)
```

Answer (score 0):

Folling the exemple from @mguijarr, bellow have an code keeping first empty cell on matrix and stripping spaces from cells borders.

```py
def parseAsciiTable(ascii_table: str):
  header = []
  data = []
  for line in ascii_table.split('\n'):
    if '-+-' in line: continue
    cells = list(filter(lambda x: x!='|', line.split('|')))
    striped_cells = list(map(lambda c: c.strip(), cells))
    if not header:
      header = striped_cells
      continue
    data.append(striped_cells)
    
  return header, data
```